# I want to uninstall older version of iOS App before reinstallation

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I've created an app, which has install button. By tapping these buttons user can install an Enterprise application (In-House). But it just replaces the existing version present in the device, so all data present in the document directory remains there. I want a fresh installation that means it should uninstall any existing version of the app and the reinstall newer version.

```
    let installableLinkStr = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://djoglobal.box.com/shared/static/jldbxp0mg4668jne2xuif8i43mh8dzwd.plist"

    guard let url = URL(string: installableLinkStr) else {
        print("Couldn't create URL")
        return
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
```

Comment: You should erase data in those apps after an update, it should be simple.

Comment: I didn't write this app. I do not know how many things there would. Ex. UserDefaultf, DB, JSON files etc. So how I can blindly clean everything?

Comment: After identify user has upgrading application, you can remove all files and clear database. You write code that clear unwanted files and folders from app sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to completely delete the application I would recommend you implement a version migration routine in the application you are updating. The general strategy:

1. On launch check if the current version is an update. You can determine if the current version is an update by persisting `CFBundleShortVersionString` in user defaults and then checking to see if the current `CFBundleShortVersionString` is the same as the string stored in user defaults and handle the result appropriately.Don't forget to persist the new `CFBundleShortVersionString` on update for future version checks.
2. Delete appropriate files from the Documents directory on update. You could delete the contents of the documents directory OR preferably store the transient documents in a nested directory that only contains files you want to delete on version change.

```js
// in your app delegate
func application(_: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    if isVersionUpdate {
        // Delete unwanted documents.
    }
    return true
}

var isVersionUpdate: Bool {
    if let documentsVersion = documentsVersion {
        return appVersion != documentsVersion
    }
    return false
}

var documentsVersion: String? {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DocumentsVersion")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "DocumentsVersion")
    }
}

var appVersion: String {
    guard let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String,
        !version.isEmpty
    else { fatalError("Argh, no version?!?!") }
    return version
}
```

Note: this answer does not take into account and whether the current version number it is higher than stored.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, using an MDM is another solution and may be all you need. However, I stand by the importance of controlling the update process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MDM for your's in-house apps.
You will be able to send to MDM-server command to reinstall app.
MDM-server will be able to uninstall and install app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the data from document folder including database, json etc.
Yes, you can delete these things blindly, it won't create any problem. Because if you are planning to delete the app and re-install it again, in that case you are not bothering about the data it has. So you can have a reset function written which clears everything, and in this kind of scenario you can just call this function on launch of new application.(This can be detected by version of the application.)